# access to two dimensional Dynamic Array with different types

Tags: c#, arrays

I found this code to generate a two dimensional Dynamic Array with different types but how can i access for example: ar[0]->o[0] ?

Thx!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Collections
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
            object[] o = new object[3];
            // Add 10 items to arraylist
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                // Create some sample data to add to array of objects of different types.
                Random r = new Random();
                o[0] = r.Next(1, 100);
                o[1] = "a" + r.Next(1,100).ToString();
                o[2] = r.Next(1,100);
                ar.Add(o);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you even want this code that you found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
((object[])ar[1])[2]
```

to obtain the third object in the second array, but be aware that you must cast this to the proper type since you are using an object array.

I would instead rather recommend this approach, create your own class that will hold your data. That way you won't need to take care of casting the object to proper types.

```
public class Randoms
{
     public int Rand1 { get; set; }
     public string Rand2 { get; set; }
     public int Rand3 { get; set; }
}
```

and then use the Generic List

```
List<Randoms> = new List<Randoms>();
```

So at the end the code would look like this:

```
List<Randoms> ar = new List<Randoms>();
// Add 10 items to list
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
       Randoms rand = new Randoms();
       Random r = new Random();
       rand.Rand1 = r.Next(1, 100);
       rand.Rand2 = "a" + r.Next(1, 100).ToString();
       rand.Rand3 = r.Next(1, 100);
       ar.Add(rand);
}
```